# Plotting in Python using matplotlib

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a graph of data, which requires the `matplotlib` module in python, but I keep getting an error message.

```
import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 125, in <module>
    raise ImportError("matplotlib requires pyparsing")
ImportError: matplotlib requires pyparsing
```

So I went on the website to downloading pyparsing and I run the code they gave us:

```
easy_install pyparsing
```

or if that doesn't work

```
easy_install http://cheeseshop.python.org/packages/source/p/pyparsing/pyparsing-2.0.1.tar.gz
```

but neither is working. What am I doing wrong? I am using the Spyder IDE.

Comment: What does "*but neither is working*" mean?

Comment: gives me an 'invalid syntax' error

Comment: You need to run `easy_install pyparsing` on the command line, not within your Python file.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked! Thank you. So I am trying to plot a graph as I mentioned and I created an example variable x=range(1,100) and I used the plot command in matplotlib. plot(x,x^2) but I got the error "unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'list' and 'int'" What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @jessica This is not part of the original question, you should write a new one.